# XAML x:bind oneTime on initially null property still works. Why?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

x:Bind defaults to OneTime, which updates the target UI with the data when the Page's Loading event triggers the generated code's Initialize function.

I have a Page with a ViewModel property. This ViewModel class implements INPC for its properties. The data for the viewModel is loaded asynchronously, only after the page is loaded. So on Page initialization, and subsequently the generated code initialization, the UI target using x:Bind will have null data.

Since it is OneTime, it shouldn't change unless I manually call Update(which I don't).

So why does my x:Bind UI work?

The following is some simplified code snippets.

```
<Page x:Name="MyPage" x:Class="MyProject.Pages.MyPage">
  <Button Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.GoToAnotherPageCommand}">


public sealed partial class MyPage : Page
{
    public MyPageViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

    public MyPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    // called by an event bound to a Frame's Navigated, which all pages use
    public void OnNavigatedTo()
    {
        this.ViewModel = new MyPageViewModel();
    }
}

public class MyPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
{
    // GoToAnotherPageCommand is an INPC property and its set in the constructor
```

Comment: Summing up Justin's answer, the Loading event for a Page occurs before the Navigated event for a Frame, so calling .Navigate for a Page with ViewModel initialization done on Navigated will have data available when OneTime x:Bind gets the data's value. One exception to this is asynchronous initialization of data which won't be guaranteed to be ready by the time the Loading event is raised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that your command works fine is because `OnNavigatedTo` will be called **before** the command instantiation. This means by the time the code tries to set the command, the `ViewModel` has already been instantiated and is no longer `null`.

To prove my point, first go open the file under the following path(could be *ARM* or *x64 depending on which platform you are running on) -

> *obj/x86/Debug/MyPage.g.cs*

This is basically the code-generated file that hooks up all the `x:Bind` stuff for your page.

Now put a *breakpoint* at where the command is set. In my case, it's a method called `Set_Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Primitives_ButtonBase_Command`.  Then put another *breakpoint* at `OnNavigatedTo`.

Now run the app, you will see that the `OnNavigatedTo` method gets called first.

If your page's `NavigationCacheMode` is set to `Disabled`, this behavior makes `OnNavigatedTo` the ideal place to instantiate `x:Bind` bindings so the page only uses memory to create these new objects when the user actually navigates to it, instead of doing everything inside the page constructor.

Don't do this inside the `Loaded` event of the `Page` though. Because it will get called **after** the command instantiation. You can try the following code to instantiate the `ViewModel`, and the result is very different(your command will not work).

```
public MyPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Loaded += (s, e) => ViewModel = new MyPageViewModel();
}
```

Comment: Ok, so is it true that when we call .Navigate on a Frame, its Navigated event will fire before the Page's Loading event is raised?

Answer (score 1):

The compiled binding system (`x:Bind`) is smart enough to check for initial null values and not consider them the actual value you wish to bind. It will wait for the first non-null value and bind that value.

This is by design, as binding to an initial null value is (almost) never the intention of the binding.

I didn't find the source of this information, but I believe it was in the Build talk detailing the x:Bind system in 2015.

---

**Updated:**

As Justin mentions in the comments below and in his own answer, the binding will not work if the view model is set after the binding operation happens.

I believe this is because the binding terminates when it encounter a null reference in the property chain, but I haven't tested this, so I might be incorrect.

Comment: If this is the case, try setting it in Loaded, and the command will no longer work. I don't think this is correct.

Comment: Would it with regular bindings though? `ViewModel` is not an INPC nor a DP, so the binding wouldn't get notified of the property change

Comment: Actually I just thought about this again with traditional binding, which only starts evaluating bindings *after* the data context is assigned. So even inside Loaded, it should work as well. +1